# Is it absolutely leaks when "self" appeared in block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, block, grand-central-dispatch

```
- (void)netServiceDidResolveAddress:(NSNetService *)service {
    dispatch_async(self.downloadQueue, ^{
        NSData *data = [self downloadFromRemoteService:service];

        dispatch_async(self.storeQueue, ^{
            int img = [self.imageStore addImage:data];

            dispatch_saync(self.renderQueue, ^{
                [self renderThumbnail:img];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [[self thumbnailViewForId:img] setNeedsDisplay:YES];
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

this is the code from Apple WWDC2012 《￼Asynchronous Design Patterns with Blocks, GCD, and》，'self' as strong reference in blocks, Is this code all right? or how to avoid leaks in this situation？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `self` will not leak. `self` will however retained until after the last block has been executed. When the last block finished, the block gets deallocated which in turn releases `self`.  At that time, and only IFF there are no other strong references to `self`, it will be deallocated.

Edit:

I could not resist to mention this (because the sample is from Apple himself -- take it with a grain if salt ;) )

So, at the very top there is the method `downloadFromRemoteService`. It's glaringly obvious that this is a network request. Network requests are *inherently* _asynchronous_.

One attribute of an asynchronous operation is that this operation cannot be made "synchronous" in a truly manner anymore. Once asynchronous - always asynchronous.

What's also obvious from the code sample, that the network request is oddly enough *synchronous*, Ohps!

What happens when wrapping a asynchronous task into a synchronous wrapper? Well, its at least "suboptimal": the calling thread will be blocked immediately until the result is available, then just return the result. That's a quite big amount of waste for resources (threads are limited and are costly to create and require a quite amount of RAM).

So, this code has a "code smell". It's a "bad programming practice". We should make this better.   ;)

Answer (score 0):

Objects automaticaly retained when mentioned in block. They got released when block deallocated. So this code is all right. Problems occur when your's self-object takes ownership of such blocks with self inside.
So you just need to release block when you don't need it any more.

Comment: This is actually a correct answer (+1) in order to balance. Blame the ignoramuses  ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a retain cycle in this code, as `self` retains `self.downloadQueue` (and the other queues), which retains all the blocks dispatched to it, including the block here, which in turn retains `self` when it is copied (which happens when it is dispatched to the queue).

However, it is a *temporary* retain cycle, because once the block is executed on the queue, the queue will (hopefully) release it, breaking the cycle.